# Implementing push menu on any webpage

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, google-chrome-extension

I have a google extension that injects an Iframe that displays tab information onto every site.

The extension can manipulate the content of the webpage e.g. html & css of the loaded page.

How can I do it such that the menu can be inline with the webpage and takes up 300px on the side with the rest of the webpage content pushed aside?

My current attempt to do that is via:

Set margin-left: 30vh on body and set the iFrame with position: absolute with 30vh of width

Comment: There is no universal solution in Chrome. It will be broken on lots of sites and there's nothing you can do about it except adding per-site workarounds. Some other browsers like Firefox or Opera provide a Sidebar API for extensions.

Comment: @wOxxOm That's the conclusion I came to too. Thank you!